# В чём разница между этими двумя header? И какой из них верный?

Tags: php, http

```
header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");
header("Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable");
```

Или вот ещё вариант:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable");
```

Answer (score 2):

Послать заголовок http 503, старый вариант.

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Retry-After: 3600
```

Лучше написать ето `(БЕРИ ЕТО)` более дополненный вариант:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Retry-After: 300
```

`3600` - `300` ЭТО СЕКУНДЫ!

Хорошо действуют на поисковые машины, они подумают что ваш сайт того и зайдет через `Retry-After` секунд.

Послать заголовок 404, сам точно не знаю с HTTP/1.0 или HTTP/1.1, вот что отправляют сайты в случае 404.

YANDEX: "`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`" (curl -I https://yandex.ru/55)

GOOGLE: "`HTTP/2 404`" (XAXXA!! curl -I https://google.com/55)

stackoverflow.com: "`HTTP/2 404`" (curl -I https://stackoverflow.com/55)

Как видно современные используют `HTTP/2` но если заметить это версия. Рассписывать различия в версиях это трудоба.

Comment: Это реально делается через функцию `header`? А то статус-код - это несколько не заголовок ведь.

Comment: По другому вы не передадите заголовки с помощью php. Функция header из пхп header — Отправка HTTP заголовка . http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: Статус код это заголовок:)

Comment: А чем лучше? В чём разница то?

Comment: Прикольно... php - такой php...

Comment: Или вот ещё вопрос: 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' или 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'? Как лучше указывать?

Comment: Попробовал на примере современных сайтов, какоже они заголовок на 404 отправляют. los "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" , YANDEX "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found". Результаты получены с помощью LINUX и " curl -I https://yandex.ru/55  "